# How to evaluate Lua in substitution field instead of vim script?

Tags: neovim, substitute, lua

As simple example, take this:

```
:'<,'>s/\vs([A|B])\.size\(\)/\={"A":"a","B":"b"}[submatch(1)]/g
```

This substitution will replace `sA.size()` with `a` and `sB.size()` with `b`.

I would like to use lua syntax after `\=` command. So it will be something like

```
:'<,'>s/\vs([A|B])\.size\(\)/\={A="a",B="b"}["%1"]/g
```

Is it possible to do that in nvim? I could not find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is:

```
:'<,'>s/\vs([A|B])\.size\(\)/\=luaeval('({A="a",B="b"})["'..submatch(1)..'"]')/g
```

The expression first build the `({A="a", B="b"})["A"]` sub-expression using `submatch` using VimScript concatenation `..` operator.

It is evaluated as a Lua expression in a second step by `luaeval`.

Comment: That's amazing that this is working! I wonder what you did by `'..submatch(1)..'`. Why there is a `'` inside a `"` and concatenation `..` inside a `"'`? Where I can read more about this?

Comment: The expression first build the `({A="a",B="b"})["A"]` sub-expression using `submatch` using VimScript concaténation `..` operator. It is evaluated as a Lua expression in a second step.